# How to stop users creating new price lists in CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have a CRM 2011 deployment which has 3 set price lists for showing different prices for 3 different types of customers. Due to the nature of the business users have to be able to create new products however I do not want to allow users to be able to create new price lists.

Currently they can do both and some users not understanding the concepts of price lists have been creating their own price lists and causing confusing for everybody else.

Anyone know what permission I can use to prevent users doing this ? I cant find a PriceList entity in the CRM dynamics permissions.

Answer (score 2):

There are no permissions about Price List (`PriceLevel`) entity.

[MSDN - PriceLevel (Price List) Entity Privileges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334596.aspx)

If you want to stop users to create new price lists you can create a synchronous plugin.

First you create a role called `Price List Enabled Users` and assign to the users that have the rights to create price lists.

The plugin (registered on `Create` message) will check if the current user has this particular role, if not it will throw an exception and the new price list will not be created.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just create a workflow that is triggered on the creation of a price list that stipulates something like. .

"If Modified By User's Team does not equal xxxx then 'stop workflow' as 'cancelled'". This will prevent the user from saving the record.You can also enter a message in to the error that they receive advising that they do not have permission to perform this action.